# How to get dict from html?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

In html i have elements like this:

```html
<script class="ember-view" id="ember36032292" name="schema:podcast-show" type="application/ld+json">
   {"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"CreativeWork","name":"A2C Random talk","author":"a2crandom","description":"We tackle tech. We tackle tv. We tackle everything","datePublished":"Oct 12, 2015","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","price":"Free"}],"review":[],"workExample":[{"@type":"AudioObject","name":"just a test for itunes","datePublished":"Oct 12, 2015","description":"test test test","duration":"PT7S","requiresSubscription":"no"}]}
  </script>
```

How can I get this string as a dictionary?
I get this line like this:

```py
description = soup.find('script', {'name': 'schema:podcast-show'}).get_text()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says `type="application/ld+json"`, [which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD) is a form of JSON.

So we use `json.loads`:

```
In [1]: import json                                                                                      

In [2]: json.loads('''{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"CreativeWork","name":"A2C Random talk","au
   ...: thor":"a2crandom","description":"We tackle tech. We tackle tv. We tackle everything","datePublish
   ...: ed":"Oct 12, 2015","offers":[{"@type":"Offer","price":"Free"}],"review":[],"workExample":[{"@type
   ...: ":"AudioObject","name":"just a test for itunes","datePublished":"Oct 12, 2015","description":"tes
   ...: t test test","duration":"PT7S","requiresSubscription":"no"}]}''')                                
Out[2]: 
{'@context': 'http://schema.org',
 '@type': 'CreativeWork',
 'name': 'A2C Random talk',
 'author': 'a2crandom',
 'description': 'We tackle tech. We tackle tv. We tackle everything',
 'datePublished': 'Oct 12, 2015',
 'offers': [{'@type': 'Offer', 'price': 'Free'}],
 'review': [],
 'workExample': [{'@type': 'AudioObject',
   'name': 'just a test for itunes',
   'datePublished': 'Oct 12, 2015',
   'description': 'test test test',
   'duration': 'PT7S',
   'requiresSubscription': 'no'}]}
```